# Visual Studio 2015 async variables not showing in debugger

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've got a .NET Core ASP.NET MVC 6 application and what I'm convinced is a bug in Visual Studio. If I place a break point after an await statement, the object does not show up in Locals, and I cannot mouse over to inspect. But if I use the variable, it still works fine, and it's definitely populated.

Something as simple as this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var location = await _listingLocationService.GetLocationByAddress("123 Fake Street");
        return Content(location.Latitude.ToString() + " " +location.Longitude.ToString());
    }
```

If I place the break point on the return statement, I cannot inspect location. It doesn't show up anywhere. I can even remove the await & place a .Result at the end, and still nothing shows. But when I continue, the view displays location.latitude, and location.longitude fine. So I know it's being populated.

For the sake of completeness, I'll include the GetLocationByAddress function as well, which does the same thing, if I place a breakpoint anywhere after the awaits, I can't inspect the variables (even the deserialized list!).

```
public async Task<Geolocation> GetLocationByAddress(string address)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json");
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "?address=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(address) + "&key=...");
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var locationResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleLocationResult>(contents);
                if (locationResult.status == "OK")
                {
                    var result = locationResult.results.First().geometry.location;
                    return new Geolocation
                    {
                        Latitude = result.lat,
                        Longitude = result.lng
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello adam3039, did you found any solution to this? Or at least it's cause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after loosing all day with this issue I've finally found the source of the problem and also the solution...
In my case, the problem has started after updating my project to use the .net core 1.1 Preview 1 following the steps shown here: [Link to MSFT .NET Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/25/announcing-net-core-1-1-preview-1/)

The problem was caused by this line of code in the project.json file:

```
"buildOptions": {
  "debugType": "portable",   <---- THIS
  "preserveCompilationContext": true,
  "emitEntryPoint": true
}
```

after setting "debugType" to "full", awaited variables started to show again while debugging.

Hope it helps to somebody outthere!

Answer (score -2):

It's not a bug. When the debugger hits the return line, it's because the previous line immediately returned a Task object. Your GetLocation method isn't done running yet (which makes sense since it's making an outbound HTTP call that will absolutely take longer than the milliseconds it took to return a Task). When you hit the return line, your debugger has stopped there, but the incomplete task means that location won't be ready. A better place to put a breakpoint is probably in the return line of your GetLocation method.

And by the way, you'll get a null ref error in your action method if the call made to Google Maps fails.

Comment: I've put the break points all over the code, including the return line of the get location method, the variables are not available for inspection. I've done this a million times in MVC 5, which is why I believe I'm experiencing a bug. I understand async/await and why it wouldn't be evaluated until it is used.

Comment: Jeff, you're wrong... the previous line doesn't return a Task object, because it's "awaited" so you should get the result of the async call in the variable... I'm experiencing the erratic behaviour described in the question now, suddenly. My async calls are to the database, by meanings of EF Core. It seems a bug...